# How to make Texture2D Readable via script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, texture2d

I want to make user able to decode the QR image loaded from the gallery, I have found a plugin to explore and load the image as a texture2D, but to decode that QR code, the Texture2D has to be readable/writable, And I checked the plugin, for Android it's doing the exploring and loading stuff with a jar and in IOS platform it's using a packaged library, so I have no access to the code of the lib,

I have searched for the answer, the most solution was to change the importing setting of texture in the Unity inspector, but since this is a texture loaded by code, there is not an inspector setting available for that, So my question is:

Is there any way to make this loaded texture read/writeable by code? without having to access the lib code?

Thanks

Here is the code that could get the texture by [this plugin](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/cn/#!/content/28597)

```
void OnImageLoad(string imgPath, Texture2D tex, ImageAndVideoPicker.ImageOrientation imgOrientation)
{
    Debug.Log("Image Location : " + imgPath);
    Debug.Log("Image Loaded : " + imgPath);
    texture = tex;
    Texture2D readableText = new Texture2D(tex.width, tex.height);
    readableText.LoadImage(tex.GetRawTextureData());

    string url = QRCodeDecodeController.DecodeByStaticPic(readableText);
    StartCoroutine(GetSceneAndLoadLevel(url));
}
```

As you can see, I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34850298/2288944) But got no luck.

And here is the error that showed by Android:

```
06-23 21:47:32.853: I/Unity(10557): (Filename: D Line: 0)
06-23 21:47:33.784: E/Unity(10557): Texture needs to be marked as Read/Write to be able to GetRawTextureData in player
06-23 21:47:33.784: E/Unity(10557): UnityEngine.Texture2D:GetRawTextureData()
06-23 21:47:33.784: E/Unity(10557): TestQR:OnImageLoad(String, Texture2D, ImageOrientation) (at D:\Unity Projects\nnkp\Assets\Scripts\QR\TestQR.cs:123)
06-23 21:47:33.784: E/Unity(10557): <LoadImage>c__Iterator0:MoveNext()
06-23 21:47:33.784: E/Unity(10557): UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:17)
06-23 21:47:33.784: E/Unity(10557): [./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/TextureBindings.gen.cpp line 512]
```

**Note**:

The source `Texture2D` is coming from a plugin, I can't set it to Read/Write Enabled from the Editor or use the Editor's `TextureImporter.isReadable` variable.

Comment: Where are you getting the read error? Post the line of code.

Comment: @Programmer, nice to see your again, Have just edited to post the log

Comment: Read your question again and decided to delete the old one. I missed an important line there which is the `Texture2D.LoadImage` function you used. Let me know if everything is fine now.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

**1**.Use `RenderTexture` (Recommended):

Use `RenderTexture`. Put the source `Texture2D` into `RenderTexture` with `Graphics.Blit` then use `Texture2D.ReadPixels` to read the image from `RenderTexture` into the new `Texture2D`.

```
Texture2D duplicateTexture(Texture2D source)
{
    RenderTexture renderTex = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(
                source.width,
                source.height,
                0,
                RenderTextureFormat.Default,
                RenderTextureReadWrite.Linear);

    Graphics.Blit(source, renderTex);
    RenderTexture previous = RenderTexture.active;
    RenderTexture.active = renderTex;
    Texture2D readableText = new Texture2D(source.width, source.height);
    readableText.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, renderTex.width, renderTex.height), 0, 0);
    readableText.Apply();
    RenderTexture.active = previous;
    RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(renderTex);
    return readableText;
}
```

**Usage**:

```
Texture2D copy = duplicateTexture(sourceTextFromPlugin);
```

This should work and should not throw any error.

---

**2**.Use `Texture2D.GetRawTextureData()` + `Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData()`:

You can't use `GetPixels32()` because the `Texture2D` is not readable. You were so close about using `GetRawTextureData()`.

You failed when you used `Texture2D.LoadImage()` to load from `GetRawTextureData()`.

*`Texture2D.LoadImage()` is **only** used to load PNG/JPG array bytes not Texture2D array byte.*

If you read with `Texture2D.GetRawTextureData()`, you must write with `Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData()` not `Texture2D.LoadImage()`.

```
Texture2D duplicateTexture(Texture2D source)
{
    byte[] pix = source.GetRawTextureData();
    Texture2D readableText = new Texture2D(source.width, source.height, source.format, false);
    readableText.LoadRawTextureData(pix);
    readableText.Apply();
    return readableText;
}
```

There will be no error with the code above in the Editor but there should be an error in standalone build. Besides, it should still work even with the error in the standalone build. I think that error is more like a warning.

I recommend you use method **#1** to do this as it will not throw any error.

Comment: Hi. still got `06-24 16:27:31.295: E/Unity(19300): Texture needs to be marked as Read/Write to be able to GetRawTextureData in player` error with the line of `byte[] pix = source.GetRawTextureData();`

Comment: Check my updated answer.  I think you should re-read my answer. Use #1 so that you won't get error.

Comment: Hi, @Programmer, trying the first method was the first thing I got up from bed :D  and it works! thanks for saving my day... Again! And I found it very hard to understand the mechanism of Unity's texture2D, have been struggling for this kind of problem for at least 2 times, especially about the read/write stuff, if may I ask to throw me some more material to read on? :D thanks! thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. What exactly about`Texture2D` do you not understand?

Comment: By making it unreadable, it becomes very very fast. Making it readable comes at a cost of memory and performance. The reason for this is because making it unreadable will make the texture on the GPU. If you make it readable, the CPU can also access it making the operation slow. GPU is extremely fast. That's the thing. I think you should study "Compute shader" in Unity. You will see how fast you can do stuff with it just because it's running on the GPU instead of CPU. Note that this is an advanced topic.  It's similar to making Texture2D unreadable.

Comment: Hi, I have fallow first procedure for making texture2d as readable. It's working fine but quality of image will be loose. How can we get original image without loosing quality.

Comment: @sahithi You should probably try the solution 2 if the first one has issues

Comment: Awesome! 1 solution is working like a charm. You are my hero :D

Comment: I included the first method into my project, and it leads to "applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning" on iPhone and an app crash.

Comment: for exr  loaded at runtime, Texture2D.GetRawTextureData() works but it throws for other formats e.g. Texture2D.GetRawTextureData<Color>() ->UnityException: Texture 'xxx' is not readable, the texture memory can not be accessed from scripts. You can make the texture readable in the Texture Import Settings.

Answer (score 0):

The first method is excellent. However, the generated image may have color differences. To avoid this, change:

```
RenderTextureReadWrite.Linear
```

to:

```
RenderTextureReadWrite.Default
```

This way the generated image will have no color difference.