# Creating a Sprite in size

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, sprite

I have a gallery scene and I want to load PNG's from Persistence path .

The thing is that I want them as thumbnails, theirs no need for me to load the full size file .

How can I defined the scale of the sprite?
that the relevant line for the creating of the sprite:

```
  Sprite sp1 = Sprite.Create(texture1, new Rect(0, 0, texture1.width, texture1.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 100, 0, SpriteMeshType.FullRect);
```

and that the texture creating code:

```
 Texture2D takeScreenShotImage(string filePath)
{
    Texture2D texture = null;
    byte[] fileBytes;
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        texture = new Texture2D(1, 1, TextureFormat.ETC2_RGB, false);

        texture.LoadImage(fileBytes);
    }
    return texture;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper place to make that change is on the `Texture2D` after loading the Texture. If you really want to load them as thumbnails and want the size to be smaller to save memory then resize it with the `Texture2D.Resize` function after loading the Texture. The height and width of 60 should be fine. You can then create Sprite from it with `Sprite.Create`.

```
Texture2D takeScreenShotImage(string filePath)
{
    Texture2D texture = null;
    byte[] fileBytes;
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        texture = new Texture2D(1, 1, TextureFormat.ETC2_RGB, false);

        texture.LoadImage(fileBytes);
    }

    //RE-SIZE THE Texture2D
    texture.Resize(60, 60);
    texture.Apply();

    return texture;
}
```

Note that `TextureFormat.ETC2_RGB` is compressed. To resize it you may have to create a copy of it. See #1 solution from my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44734346/3785314) post on how to do this.

Comment: I added "texture.Resize(texture.width/2, texture.height/2);" ,  and i'm getting an "empty" file , I can see in the inspector that the resize worked but the file all alpha. What can be the problem ?

Comment: Not sure but try to provide the texture format and mipmap. Use `texture.Resize(60, 60, TextureFormat.ETC2_RGB, false);`

Comment: I tried , but no luck. Any Resize that I'm doing resolve with an alpha image.

Comment: Enable mipmap both where you're creating the texture and resizing it

Comment: when I add texture format I'm getting "Can't resize to a compressed texture format". When enabling mipmap I get "failed to create 2D texture id=568 width=1 height=1 mips=3 dxgifmt=28 [D3D error was 80070057]"  edit: after changing the texture format tp ARGB32 , the error's are gone but I still having an all alpha image.

Comment: The texture you have seems to be compressed. I suggest you duplicate or make a copy of the texture then try to resize it that one. See #1 solution from my [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44734346/3785314) post on how to do this

Comment: I out of the office, I will try it firs thing tomorrow morning.  Making a duplicate of the textures won't take a lot of memory and preformance?

Comment: `ETC2_RGB` = compressed format. By making a copy of it, you will remove the compression on the new texture. You can destroy the new texture after that with the `Destroy` function

Comment: Ok , I tried to make a cope and it kind of works . The texture is resized and I can see it , the only problem is that the resizing don't take the whole texture , it's change only the file size . So after changing it to "source.Resize(source.width / 2, source.height / 2);" i can see only the 50% of the with and height of the original.

Comment: I forgot to say that you have to call `texture.Apply();` after resizing it. Please do this and the issue should be solved. Edited my answer to reflect that.